# Reading file bytes at a time

Tags: node.js, file, response, mjpeg

So I am trying to read a file bytes at a time. basically I should read the first 50 bytes, then the next 7 bytes should tell me the length x. I then read x bytes and repeat the steps until end of file. I am stuck. Do not know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

```
app.get('/video', function (req, res) {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream('video.mjpeg');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-      replace;boundary=ThisString'});

    readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {

        console.log(chunk.length); //this always gives me the same number.

        res.write(chunk, 'binary');

        console.log("Writing to client");
    });

    readStream.on("end", () => {
        readStream.destroy();
        res.end();
        console.log("End of data");
    });
});
```

Basically I want to group the data into frames. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5784782/6121703 ?

Comment: But how do I get the contents of the bytes?

Comment: Obviously, read data stores in buffer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read binary files byte by byte in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784621/how-to-read-binary-files-byte-by-byte-in-node-js)