# Pass Binary string/file content from c++ to node js

Tags: c++, node.js, binary, node-gyp

I'm trying to pass the content of a binary file from c++ to node using the node-gyp library. I have a process that creates a binary file using the .fit format and I need to pass the content of the file to js to process it. So, my first aproach was to extract the content of the file in a string and try to pass it to node like this.

```
   char c;
   std::string content="";
   while (file.get(c)){
    content+=c;
   }
```

I'm using the following code to pass it to Node

```
v8::Local<v8::ArrayBuffer> ab = v8::ArrayBuffer::New(args.GetIsolate(), (void*)content.data(), content.size());
args.GetReturnValue().Set(ab);
```

In node a get an arrayBuffer but when I print the content to a file it is different to the one that show a c++ cout.

How can I pass the binary data succesfully?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your binary data printable?  A lot of *binary* data values are not printable.

Comment: Like @Thomas said, how does your _binary data_ look like? Do you use some encoding?

Comment: You should *write* content of this buffer to the file instead of *printing* it.

Comment: I read the binary data from a binary file  with this code: `char c;
   std::string content="";
   while (file.get(c)){
    content+=c;
   }`  I need to pass the content of the file to node, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: You should open file in binary mode and read entire file content using [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method. Though you can do this in node itself.

Comment: The library I'm using creates the binary file from a json file with some specifications, but I need to pass the content of the file to node instead of saving it from c++. The idea is to use the content of the file later in a larger aplication.

Comment: @jmahecha have you looked into redis?

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably the best approach is to write your data to a binary disk file.  Write to disk in C++; read from disk in NodeJS.
2. Very importantly, make sure you specify *BINARY MODE*.

   For example:

   `myFile.open ("data2.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);`
3. Do not use "strings" (at least not unless you want to uuencode).  Use buffers.  Here is a good example:

[How to read binary files byte by byte in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784621/how-to-read-binary-files-byte-by-byte-in-node-js)

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('file.txt', 'r', function(status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer(100);
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 100, 0, function(err, num) {
        ...
    });
});
```

4. You might also find these links helpful:

   - https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html
     <= Has good examples for specific Node APIs
   - http://blog.paracode.com/2013/04/24/parsing-binary-data-with-node-dot-js/
     <= Good discussion of some of the issues you might face, including "endianness" and "interpreting numbers"

ADDENDUM:

- The OP clarified that he's considering using C++ as a *NodeJS Add-On* (not a standalone C++ program.
- Consequently, using buffers is definitely an option.  Here is a good tutorial:

https://community.risingstack.com/using-buffers-node-js-c-plus-plus/

If you choose to go this route, I would DEFINITELY download the example code and play with it first, before implementing buffers in your own application.

Comment: Do you think that passing the buffer from the binary file is a bad idea? Do you think is better to save the file to disk in c++ and read it from node that try to pass the content?

Comment: Your Node program and your C++ programs are two different processes, running in two different address spaces, aren't they?  If so, then "yes", a disk file is a good choice.  Other [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) choices besides "files" might include "sockets" and/or "pipes".

Comment: The node-gyp library https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp that build bundles for node js with othe code for example c++

Comment: Fair enough: Writing a Node Add-on in C++ is also a viable alternative.  Please read my post above, and read (and try the sample code) at this link: [Scott Frees: Using Buffers to share data between Node.js and C++](https://community.risingstack.com/using-buffers-node-js-c-plus-plus/)

Comment: I check out you post and base on that I'm working on a example to pass a buffer using this code: `info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::NewBuffer(&buffer[0], size).ToLocalChecked());` I get data from node, but is not the same that in c++, maybe is because is binary data, I don't know is using this the data is transform o alter in some way. have you try ti use buffer with binary data?

Answer (score 0):

It depends but for example using redis

> Values can be strings (including binary data) of every kind, for
>   instance you can store a jpeg image inside a value. A value can't be
>   bigger than 512 MB.

If the file is bigger than 512MB, then you can store it in chunks.
But I wouldnt suggest since this is an **in-memory data store**

Its easy to implement in both c++ and node.js